# IdentityServer and client external login

Tags: identityserver4

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I was wondering, when registering a new client which uses identity server (for which we have already defined external logins), can we limit the number of these external providers?

For example, one client to support just Facebook, another just Twitter?

...or the same external logins are always used for all clients under the same identity server instance, so I would need two separate identity server instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the `Client` to support particular external provider by using the `IdentityProviderRestrictions` property.  This property contains a list of provider names that can be used for the client. Empty list (the default) means all providers allowed.

e.g.

```
new Client {
    ClientId = "yourclient",
    ClientName = "Your Client",
    .
    .
    .
    IdentityProviderRestrictions = {"Facebook", "Google"};
}
```

This property is used to filter external providers in IdentityServer's example `AccountController`:

```
    if (context?.ClientId != null)
    {
        var client = await _clientStore.FindEnabledClientByIdAsync(context.ClientId);
        if (client != null)
        {
            allowLocal = client.EnableLocalLogin;

            if (client.IdentityProviderRestrictions != null && client.IdentityProviderRestrictions.Any())
            {
                providers = providers.Where(provider => client.IdentityProviderRestrictions.Contains(provider.AuthenticationScheme)).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

In your `AccountController` you can identify the client making the authentication request using `AuthorizationRequest.ClientId`. You can then vary the login functionality based on the client making the request.

`AuthorizationRequest` can be obtained from `IIdentityServerInteractionService.GetAuthorizationContextAsync` and `IIdentityServerInteractionService` is obtained via DI.

Comment: Excellent! Is there a similar way to limit custom providers which are used to check local databases? ...or I can use this for custom local providers as well?

Comment: I have extended my answer to cover this.